# sportsBasketballChange another place its not setting state properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux

**I tried to say is I am not able to set the value using setState in sportsBasketballChange function but I am able to set it in sportsSoccerChange function**

- i am new to react.js
- i am trying to set the value using setState.
- in sportsSoccerChange function  its correctly setting setState.
- but sportsBasketballChange another place its not setting state properly.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

part of code

```
sportsSoccerChange(value) {
    this.props.onChange();

    let processedValue = value;

    // sportsMessages sportsAirFalling
    processedValue = sportsAirFallBALL(processedValue, this.props.sportsAirFall);

    // sportsSuceessOnTime-ation
    let sportsSuceessOnTime-ationResult = sportsSuceessOnTime-ateBALL(processedValue, this.props.sportsDrive);
    if (sportsSuceessOnTime-ationResult === true) {
        this.setState({ sportsOutcome: 'sportsSuceessOnTime-' });
        ///here i get value as sportsSuceessOnTime-
    }
    //this.setState({ isBALLValid: sportsSuceessOnTime-ationResult });

    // formatting
    processedValue = formatBALL(processedValue, this.props.sportsLongJump);

    // set value in local component state
    this.setState({ sportsMessagesValue: processedValue });
},

sportsBasketballChange() {
    if (this.state.sportsOutcome === 'female') {
        this.setState({ sportsOutcome: 'sportsSuceessOnTime-' });
        ///here i don't get value as sportsSuceessOnTime-
    }
},
```

whole code here

https://gist.github.com/js08/e20c02bf21242201c1525577d55dedbc

Comment: We don't really know what you're asking. We're also not a free coding service. When you find a specific, narrowed down problem, that's we're here to help.

Comment: @AaronGillion hey thanks for your reply...what I tried to say is I am not able to set the value using setState in sportsBasketballChange function but I am able to set it in sportsSoccerChange function.....

Comment: @all I tried debugging but couldn't find solution...pls dont mark it negaive

Comment: Alright. Retracted the vote. I **do** understand how painful debugging is.

Comment: @AaronGillion do you know where is the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are checking the value of `this.state` at those commented lines, either using logging or debugging.

`setState` is asynchronous.  This means that there is no guarantee that the changes have occurred by the time you reach the next line of code.  However, `setState` allows you to provide a callback function to be run after the state has finished updating.  **That** is where you should be checking the updated value.

```
sportsBasketballChange() {
    if (this.state.sportsOutcome === 'female') {
        this.setState({ sportsOutcome: 'sportsSuceessOnTime-' },
            function(){ 
                console.log(this.state.sportsOutcome); // == 'sportsSuceessOnTime-'
            }
        );
        console.log(this.state.sportsOutcome); // untrustworthy
    }
},
```

Comment: does react have any js design patterns